# calling procedure from sql

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am coding winform application where i call procedure in my datagrid.
I have method where I define parameters of procedure

```
 public int Add_Nastavenie(out int typNastav, int nastavID, string hod)
    {
        ResetParameters();
        cmd.CommandText = "add_Nastav";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter sqlParameter;

        var sqlParameterOut = new SqlParameter("@TypNastav", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlParameterOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


        sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@NastavenieID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sqlParameter.Value = nastavID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

        sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@Hodnota", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sqlParameter.Value = hod;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

        var sqlParameterRet = new SqlParameter("retValue", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlParameterRet.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        typNastav = (int)sqlParameterOut.Value;
        return (int)cmd.Parameters["retvalue"].Value;

    }
```

then i call procedure this way

```
 dataConnector.Add_Nastavenie(typNastav,nastavID,hod);
```

I have an error     Argument 1 must be passed with the 'out' keyword

I change it to   dataConnector.Add_Nastavenie(out typNastav,nastavID,hod);

error dissapear but application is not working, procedure do nothing .

My try catch exception show : Procedure or function 'add_Nastav' expects parameter '@TypNastav', which was not supplied.

Can somebody help find solution ? Thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't added the `OUTPUT` parameter the stored procedure is expecting:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParameterOut);
```

Comment: maybe I am makig still mistake but i added your code and now error is : the formal parameter "@TypNastav" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter,but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

Comment: @user2641465 - you need to make @TypNastav an OUTPUT parameter in your stored procedure.  If you do not want it as an `OUTPUT` parameter, change the direction of it to `.Input` rather than `.Output`

Comment: RETURN @typNastav OUTPUT

Comment: yes it is working but how i fix error : sql parameter with ParameterName 'retvalue' is not contained by this sqlParameterCollection ....  in this   dataConnector.Add_Nastavenie(out typNastav,nastavID,hod); . I really dont know it is first time work with procedures an application is not mine I just remake it.

Comment: @user2641465 - this sounds like a new question. You should accept an answer here (if it helped you resolve your initial problem) and then ask a new question regarding the sqlParameterCollection.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update_outptu_Stock", connect.con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cg_id ", 1);
            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };
```

SQL:

```
Create proc update_outptu_Stock 
@cg_id int,
@id int output
as
begin
    insert into example(cg_id) values (@cg_id)
    set @id  = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- get value of id created
end
Go
```

Get parameter id:

```
var parvalue = id.value;
```